# Control event works multiple times after DataContext update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a DataGrid with Template column as checkbox with check/uncheck events for some calculations and data comparison and a textbox that allows me to use search by name field and hide useless results:

**DataGrid.xaml**

```
<TextBox Name="TbSearch"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Background="#F5F5F5"
             BorderBrush="#F5F5F5"
             Padding="27,6,0,0"
             Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<DataGrid Name="DgViews"
      Grid.Row="1" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Views}">

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Tag="{Binding UniqueId}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Checked="ViewCheck"
                          Unchecked="ViewUncheck"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                        Header="View name"
                        Binding="{Binding ViewName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                        Header="View type"
                        Binding="{Binding ViewType}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**DataGridTest.xaml.cs**

```
public DataGridTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ModelDataContext();
}

private void ViewCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
}

private void ViewUncheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("UnChecked");
}
```

**ModelDataContext.cs**

```
class ModelDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string searchText = string.Empty;

    public ModelDataContext()
    {

    }

    public string SearchText
    {
        get => searchText;
        set
        {
            searchText = value;

            Views = Views.Select(n =>
            {
                if (n.ViewName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                {
                    n.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    n.IsVisible = false;
                }
                return n;
            }).ToList();

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Views"));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SearchText"));
        }
    }

    public List<ViewData> Views { get; set; }
}
```

When I type search text DataGrid items source updates every time, and via each update, check box event (check/uncheck) increases by one.
For example I type 3 letter and data grid updates 3 times, so when I check checkbox it works 3 times, but  I need just once.
How can I solve it?

Comment: could you show full code about datagrid please? xaml and c#

Comment: @Frenchy Sure. Added xaml and code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ViewData Class Update IsVisible property

```
 private bool _IsVisible;
   public bool IsVisible
     {
       get { return _IsVisible; }
       set { _IsVisible = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsVisible")); }
     }
```

Remove Re assigning Views from the SearchText,

```
 public string SearchText
    {
        get => searchText;
        set
        {
            searchText = value;

             Views.Select(n =>
            {
                if (n.ViewName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                {
                    n.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    n.IsVisible = false;
                }
                return n;
            }).ToList();

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Views"));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SearchText"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It makes sense, but when I remove re-assign part, search stops grid update.

Comment: @shss grid update stopped means, In the GUI, grid is not updated?

Comment: yep, code behind updated well, but GUI doesnt update rows

Comment: @shss Only chance is ,you might not added PropertyChanged for IsVisible

Comment: Added `Binding="{Binding IsVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"`, but doesn't work, feels like trigger doesn't work

Comment: @shss this.OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");

Comment: Had to change class structure a little bit, but it works! Thanks.